# How to see what Sphinx is actually finding?

Tags: sphinx

I am getting unexpected results from a sphinxql query from a very large database and a very complex configuration file. I'm stumped trying to figure out what i'd be getting these results. Is there anyway to return the result and simultaneously find the actual indexed data it found? I'm trying to get some insight/clue into what part of this complex configuration file to look into as line by line is e near impossibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as `SHOW META`, which itself shows much useful info...

`SHOW PLAN` - if want to diagnose the **full-text query** parsing itself
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-plan

`PACKEDFACTORS()` - function can tell you more than you need to know about how **ranking** calculated
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expr-func-packedfactors

`SHOW PROFILE` - can help with **performance** issues
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-profile

And `DESCRIBE indexname` is often useful to see exactly what **Fields and Attributes in an index**
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-describe

Finally `indextool --dumpheader` can be very useful to check the **configuration** for a specific index. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indextool
(actually its other commands can be useful too!)

Answer (score 0):

You can fire `SHOW META;` just after the sphinxql query to get the insights.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-meta