# Are there alternative/deeper ways to analyze a Sphinx Query besides `Show Meta`?

Tags: sphinx

I have a complex Sphinx Config which utilizes regepx and wordforms as well.

Often I get unexpected results and have started using `Show Meta` to see what my various manipulations are actually searching for.

I have records `1`,`2` and `3` that should each be found by `SphinxQL` `Query A` or `SphinxQL` `Query B`.  Yet only `1` and `2` are found by `Query A` and only `3` is found by `Query B`.

When I run `Show Meta` however it shows me the expected keywords for `Query A` and `Query B` are identical.

I am unclear why all 3 records are not found by either Query when they are found by one or the other which request the same keywords ultimately.

In fact if I manually do a `SphinxQL` search for the same keywords each of the original Queries ended up pushing as described by `Show Meta` I get all the records.

Is there another analysis tool in Sphinx that might help me uncover this mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well mentioned a range of tools in another post of yours
[How to see what Sphinx is actually finding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570154/how-to-see-what-sphinx-is-actually-finding)

In particular `SHOW PLAN` might be helpful, or the data from `PACKEDFACTORS()` - lots of information, but in particular can show what fields match for example.

Comment: Ah you did indeed my bad sorry. I tried `Show Profilng=1` which runs and does nothing, I noticed you initialized it as `SET profiling=1 \G` and then called it by adding the `G` at the end of your queryt. However while `Show Profiling=1` runs w/o error but does nothing, `SET profiling=1 \G`  returns  [Err] 1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end near '\G'

Comment: Hmm, dont know where you saw that. but \G is a special command for the **mysql command line client**, displays results in different format. Its not a general SQL command (so wont work from PHP etc) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html#idm140236451154224 - example here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-profile using standard semicolon seperator

Comment: I actually saw it in the `Show Plan` link you included (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-plan) which seemed like the most likely candidate to tell me what is in fact going on. I am in fact doing my testing from a mysql editor I can try again from CL. However w/o \G I get no useful information from `Show Plan` so I assumed it was necessary.